# How to dynamically set id of CCheckbox in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I am using `CCheckbox` in Yii but can't able to set its `id` name conditionally.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'task-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
     'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'task_name',
        'task_description',
        array(
            'header'=>'Close/Open',
            'id'=>'close_button',
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'selectableRows' => '10',                
            'value'=>'$data->task_id',
            'checked'=>'$data->task_status == 0 ? false : true',
            'headerTemplate'=>'<label>{item}<span></span></label>',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 20px','class'=>'chandran'),
        ),
          ),
));
```

Like checked property I am trying to set id of checkbox dynamically but it is not working.

I tried

```
 'id'=>'$data->task_status == 0 ? "close_button": "open_button"',
```

but it is not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: try `'id' => function($data){
                                $id = $data->task_status == 0 ? "close_button": "open_button";
        return $id;
                        }`

Comment: Thanks for reply but it gives me error like substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given.

Comment: what is `$data->task_status`? Maybe it is an object if you for example have status as model and got relation between task and status.